# Is there a formula to calculate the slope of N points after a minimum value in a column of values?

Tags: excel

I have variable row number columns of data. I need to find the minimum value in the first 90 rows, then calculate the slope of that value and the subsequent 59 rows, regardless of whether or not that extends past the first 100 rows. The data is collected at 1 sample per second, so our hope is to find the slope of the data for 1 minute after the minimum point.

Column `A` is time in seconds, so increases by 1 from row `A10` for as many data rows are present.

`=SLOPE(TAKE(MIN(B$10:B$99),60,),A$10:A$69)`

Results in a `#N/A` error.

I am able to find the minimum value in the first 90 values `=MIN(B$10:B$99)`

and I am able to get an average of the last 10 values of a variable length column of data:
`=AVERAGE(TAKE(B$10:OFFSET(B$10,COUNTA(B$10:B10000)-1,0),-10)),`

The formulas start at `B$10` because there are several header rows of summary data from each column.